# Behavior of a function parameter pack

Tags: c++, function, templates, variadic-templates

```
template<typename... T>
void foo(T... args);
```

In the above example, `T` is expanded according to *§14.5.3 - (4.1)* of the standard.

> §14.5.3 - (4.1) — In a function parameter pack (8.3.5); the pattern is the parameter-declaration without the ellipsis.

What exactly is happening here? Let's say I call the function with 3 integers.

```
foo(1, 2, 3);
```

Is the parameter pack being expanded like

```
foo(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3);
```

where arg1, arg2, and arg3 are just arbitrary names given to by the compiler?

The standard says how "the pattern is the parameter-declaration without the ellipsis"

The other way I interpret that is `args` gets a single parameter-declartion.Is `args` getting its own type? I've tried doing

```
std::cout << typeid(args).name;
```

but that doesn't work, and throws compiler errors. So I could assume it's not getting its own type. Could someone "dumb down" what really is happening here, and the behavior of the function parameter pack?

Comment: Can the downvoter explain why the -1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I think I've figured it out. Correct me if I'm wrong.

A parameter expansion happens when the ellipsis is on the right on the pattern. Our pattern here is simply just `T`:

```
foo(T... args);
```

The standard states that the result of this will be a `parameter-declaration`. This decays into:

> *attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> decl-specifier-seq declarator*

`attribute-specifier-seq` can be ignored.

`decl-specifier-seq` is the type, `T`;

`declarator` is `... args`

Semantically, this is a function parameter pack declaration. Nothing special.

Once again, my curiosity causes me to go insane for a little... heh.